# Counting events through the Google Analytics APIs

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to use the Google Analytics APIs get a count of the number of times a certain event has been tracked?

More specifically, can this number be counted in such a way that each unique visitor who hits this event is counted only once (subsequent events for each unique visitor are not included in the total).

I am intending to access the API through PHP, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.

You'd set your dimension to be `ga:eventCategory`, or `ga:eventAction` or `ga:eventLabel` (or two or all of them), depending on what level of the event you want to count.

You'd set your metric to be `ga:uniqueEvents`, which only counts the event once per visit. (You don't have the ability to make it unique according to visitor.) For total events, you'd set it to `ga:totalEvents`.

And you'd set your filter to filter down to which events you'd like to account for. For example, for events of category Foo and action Bar:

```
ga:eventCategory==Foo;ga:eventAction==Bar
```

You can test it out in the [Google Analytics Data Feed Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html).

Comment: You'll probably also need dimensions such as `ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel`

Answer (score 0):

Its is very easy, bit of understanding is enough... 
Follow this java code or follow this strategy in google analytics query explorer

/*** JAVA CODE ***/

```
DataQuery query = new DataQuery(new URL(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data"));

query.setStartDate("2013-08-25");

query.setEndDate("2013-09-24");

//query.setDimensions("ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath");

query.setDimensions("ga:pageTitle,ga:eventCategory");

//query.setFilters("ga:pagePath=~forgot.action");

query.setFilters("ga:eventCategory==/*Your event as per Google Analytics*/");

//query.setMetrics("ga:pageviews");

query.setMetrics("ga:uniqueEvents");

//query.setSort("-ga:pageviews");

//query.setSort("-ga:visitors");

query.setMaxResults(10);

query.setIds(/*YOUR TABLE ID*/);
```

Hope this will help a lot